# How to get absolute path of a featured image in gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

In my `createSchemaCustomization` I define the types

```
  const typeDefs = `
    type MarkdownRemark implements Node @dontInfer {
      htmlAst: Object!
      frontmatter: Frontmatter!
      fields: Fields!
    }
    
    type Frontmatter @dontInfer {
      updatedAt: Date!
      createdAt: Date!
      path: String!
      title: String!
      description: String!
      keywords: String
      layout: String
      content: Boolean
      categories: [String]
      featuredImage: File @fileByDataPath
    }
    
    type Fields @dontInfer {
      sourceInstanceName: String!
    }
  `
```

And `createFieldExtension`

```
  createFieldExtension({
    name: 'fileByDataPath',
    extend: () => ({
      resolve: async function(src, args, context, info) {
        const partialPath = src.featuredImage
        if (!partialPath) return null
        const filePath = `hardcoded full path/img.png`
        const a = context.nodeModel.getAllNodes({type: `allMarkdownRemark`})
        console.log(`>>a`, a) // Empty array
        const fileNode = await context.nodeModel.runQuery({
          firstOnly: true,
          type: 'File',
          query: {
            filter: {
              absolutePath: {
                eq: filePath,
              },
            },
          },
        })
        console.log(`fileNode`, fileNode) // Some object
        return fileNode

      },
    }),
  })
```

Then in my markdown I have

```
---
featuredImage: ./img.png
---
```

The problem I'm having is to get the absolute path of the image `./img.png` in the `context.nodeModel.runQuery`. I tried to get all posts from `allMarkdownRemark` but is empty array, not sure what else can I do?

Any ideas on how to get the absolute path of this image? First I need to get the absolute path of the markdown file, but no idea how as well.

In `createFieldExtension.extend.resolve` I only have access to frontmatter object, which includes only the path, but that's the url path of the post. I was thinking based on that to query all markdown files with that path and then get the file path somehow, but `allMarkdownRemark` is returning empty array.

Also by default gatsby doesn't seem to work because I use `@dontInfer` in the types.

Comment: You should try `context.nodeModel.getAllNodes({type: `MarkdownRemark`})` instead, since `allMarkdownRemark` is a root query & not a node type

Answer (score 1):

I ended up putting the `featuredImage` on the `MarkdownRemark` instead so I can get the file path of the markdown.

Still a bit hacky, so if you have better ideas, please let me know.

```
export const createSchemaCustomization = ({actions}) => {
  const {createFieldExtension, createTypes} = actions

  createFieldExtension({
    name: 'fileByDataPath',
    extend: () => ({
      resolve: async function(src, args, context, info) {
        const partialPath = src.frontmatter.featuredImage
        if (!partialPath) return null
        const absolutePath = path.resolve(path.dirname(src.fileAbsolutePath), partialPath).replace(/\\/g, `/`)
        const fileNode = await context.nodeModel.runQuery({
          firstOnly: true,
          type: 'File',
          query: {
            filter: {
              absolutePath: {
                eq: absolutePath,
              },
            },
          },
        })
        return fileNode
      },
    }),
  })

  const typeDefs = `
    type MarkdownRemark implements Node @dontInfer {
      htmlAst: Object!
      frontmatter: Frontmatter!
      fields: Fields!
      featuredImage: File @fileByDataPath
    }
    
    type Frontmatter @dontInfer {
      updatedAt: Date!
      createdAt: Date!
      path: String!
      title: String!
      description: String!
      keywords: String
      layout: String
      content: Boolean
      categories: [String]
      featuredImage: String
    }
    
    type Fields @dontInfer {
      sourceInstanceName: String!
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```